# Magento 2.3.2 Contact Us Form error

Tags: contact-us

Running Magento 2.3.2 and no matter what I seem to do I cannot get the contact us form to work.  I have tried all the solutions I think

**Captha - Checked**

**Email- I set up the emails in config**

**template - I set to a template**

not sure what i am missing been at it for days.

A thousand thank yous

Comment: Can you describe which error you are facing on contact Us Form?

Comment: It should simply work. Try site-url/contact or site-url/contact-us.  It will be better you add more detail . Good luck

Comment: It gives the following error and no email is sent to me.  "An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later."  if you let me know where a more detailed log of the error would be I could get that info.

Comment: the error you are getting is from controller i.e `magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php`. there should be a log for above error message at var/log directory

Comment: I searched the logs but cant find which one would contain the info do you which log it would be?